# Down casting nib uitableviewcell

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8

For my app, I wish to have a generic cell format, with the **same UI but different functionality** for each cell depending on the content.
I thought any easy way to do this was to create a subclass of uitableviewcell with @IBOutlets called ToggleCell:

```
class ToggleCell: UITableViewCell {
    // @IBOutlets here
}
```

and make a **nib file with that as its class**.  I then created a subclass of that with custom functionality called TaskCell:

```
class TaskCell: ToggleCell {
    func load() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

However, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, when I deqeue my cell, the down casting fails:

```
let cell = cellForRowAtIndexPath(...) as! TaskCell
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is there any way to do this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the cell classes on your table view using the `registerClass` method. However, there is a more fundamental issue in your approach. Your single NIB already defines the particular cell class (the super class `ToggleCell`) which cannot be downcasted to an arbitrary subclass. What you should do instead is create a NIB and class for the cell's custom content view and load it in the super class `ToggleCell`.

```
class ToggleCellContentView: UIView {

    // Connect outlets in ToggleCellContentView.xib

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

}

class ToggleCell: UITableViewCell {

    let view: ToggleCellContentView

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        // Load custom content view from NIB
        view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ToggleCellContentView",
            owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! ToggleCellContentView

        super.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // Add custom content view as subview
        contentView.addSubview(view)

        // Make custom content view span the cell
        view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        let viewDict = ["view": view]
        contentView.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewDict))
        contentView.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewDict))
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

class TaskCell: ToggleCell {

    func load() {
        // do stuff
    }

}

class OtherTaskCell: ToggleCell {

    func load() {
        // other do stuff
    }

}
```

Then just register your cell classes on the table view

```
tableView.registerClass(TaskCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "taskCell")
tableView.registerClass(OtherTaskCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "otherTaskCell")
```

and deque them in the data source method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let taskcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("taskcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TaskCell
    taskcell.view.label.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
    return taskcell
}
```

Comment: I did this and it just completely removed the cell's view - why would that happen?

Comment: do i need to specifically call init on it after dequeing?

Comment: @teo751Sorry, I forgot to  mention that after loading the custom content view from the NIB you also need to add it to the cell as a subview and make it span the cell. I updated the `init` method of `ToggleCell` above. Note, also that you don't need to call `init` explicitly in the table view's data source method. Calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` already does that for you in case no reusable cell exists.